# Jquery mask no longer works

Tags: jquery

I updated my jquery from 1.8.3 to 1.9.1, I fixed one problem but now I have 4 others :

- in jquery.mask : :4002/Scripts/jquery.mask.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference

- in : jquery.unobtrusive-ajax
  :4002/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

- in : jquery.validate
  :4002/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

- in : jquery.validate.unobtrusive
  :4002/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

how can I solve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like jquery isn't loaded.  Did you change the order in which files get loaded?

Comment: I didn't change the order, I only replaced the path to the old file with the new one

Comment: Are you using wordpress by any chance?